# Help with collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

The following produces a working select drop down that pulls from my user model:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:user_id, @users, :id, :firstname, options ={:prompt => "Select a User"} %>
```

I also have a column `:lastname`.

I am trying to populate the select with something like `:firstname + " " + :lastname`

This obviously fails if I just stick it in where :firstname is.  How would you go about concatenating the two columns and populating the select box.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your user model create a new method called `name`. Then use it in your helper.

```
class User

  def name
    "#{firstname} #{last_name}"
  end

end

<%= f.collection_select(:user_id, @users, :id, :name, :prompt => "Select a User") %>
```

Answer (score 3):

define a method full_name on the User model and then use :full_name in the collection select